# Get the primary key of a search container column

Tags: java, liferay, portlet

This is my code for the search container, I am trying to integrate update and delete method for my guestbook portlet. I have to get the primary key to be able to do it. This is what I got so far

```
<liferay-ui:search-container>
<liferay-ui:search-container-results
    results="<%=EntryLocalServiceUtil.getEntries(scopeGroupId,
                    guestbookId, searchContainer.getStart(),
                    searchContainer.getEnd())%>" />

<liferay-ui:search-container-row
    className="com.liferay.docs.guestbook.model.Entry" modelVar="entry">


    <portlet:renderURL var="updateEntryURL">
        <portlet:param name="mvcPath" value="/html/guestbook/update_entry.jsp"/>
        <portlet:param name="entryId" value="entryId"/>
    </portlet:renderURL>

    <liferay-ui:search-container-column-text property="message" />

    <liferay-ui:search-container-column-text property="name" />


    <liferay-ui:search-container-column-text name="Edit" href="#"  value="EDIT">
    </liferay-ui:search-container-column-text>
    <liferay-ui:search-container-column-text name="Delete" href="#"  value="DELETE">
    </liferay-ui:search-container-column-text>          


</liferay-ui:search-container-row>

<liferay-ui:search-iterator />
```

I am trying to get it through this part

```
    <portlet:renderURL var="updateEntryURL">
        <portlet:param name="mvcPath" value="/html/guestbook/update_entry.jsp"/>
        <portlet:param name="entryId" value="entryId"/>
    </portlet:renderURL>
```

but I currently have no idea how could I get the entry id. I am very new to this framework.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line

```
<liferay-ui:search-container-row
className="com.liferay.docs.guestbook.model.Entry" modelVar="entry">
```

holds the key to your answer: `modelVar="entry"`.

In the scope of that tag, you can do, for example, `<%=entry.getId()%>` (or use the EL version of this expression). You basically have a variable named `entry` available in scope

Comment: I didn't expect it would come from that. Anyway thanks, now I know how to play with it's code. Thanks a lot man!